# Selenium python combine webdrivers into one browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, multiprocessing

In order to open multiple sites at the same time, I have to use multiple webdrivers (and multiprocess to do it simultaneously) to utilize .get() that it has. However, it's very expensive memory-wise to open multiple windows at the same time. I'm wondering if it's possible to combine all these browsing instances into one window (e.g. 1 webdrivers = 1 tab (instead of window)).

Or even better, would it be possible to open multiple tabs and control them independently (e.g. using .get() and retrieve contents in each tab) using only 1 webdriver.

Using headless is not an option because in my case it is necessary to look at the process directly (for presentation purposes).